# If $U$ is an upper triangular matrix such that $\det U \neq 0$ then there exists an upper triangular matrix $U^{-1}$ such that $UU^{-1}=I$.

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

> If $U$ is an upper triangular matrix such that $\det U \neq 0$ then there exists an upper triangular matrix $U^{-1}$ such that $UU^{-1}=I$.

Note: I have not been introduced to the concepts of Eigenvalues, Eigenvectors, adjoint, adjugate.

I know that the determinant of an upper triangular $n \times n$ matrix is the product of its diagonal entries. If
$$
\det U \neq 0$$
then, that means none of the diagonal entries of $U$ is zero. But what I can deduce from it? Upto now, I have been taught that a matrix is invertible if and only if the corresponding linear transformation $T$ is invertible (which we can check by if T is one-to-one); now the matrix is completely on its own, and I have no way to tell if it's invertible.

I'm in need of a direction.

Comment: Well, if you want to be really elementary about it what you are looking for is a matrix $A$ such that $AU = UA = I$, right? Well, write down the corresponding system of equations, and you will see that this system is solvable if the determinant of $U$ is not zero. Try for a $2\times 2$ matrix first if you do not want to write too much.

Comment: Phrasing @JohannesPauling's comment another way: Try to use the row reduction (Gausss-Jordan elimination) algorithm to compute the inverse. You'll see that the inverse will necessarily be upper triangular.

Comment: Do you know that $U$ is invertible if and only if its determinant is nonzero?

Answer (score 1):

I would offer a mildly informal "proof" of this fact. You know that the inverse $U^{-1}$ will satisfy $U^{-1}U = I$. We can write out the system of equations that $U^{-1}U = I$ must satisfy for it to be consistent, where we let $e_i$ represent the vector where the $i$th component is $1$ and the rest are $0$ and let the columns of $U^{-1}$ be denoted $u_i^*$.

The system is:

\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
u_1^*u_{11} = e_1 \\
u_1^*u_{12} + u_2^*u_{22} = e_2 \\
\dots \\
\sum_{j=1}^n u_j^*u_{jn} = e_n
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
You can solve this system by first solving the first equation and then directly plugging this solution into the next equation. Doing so we will end up with $u_1^* = \frac{1}{u_{11}}e_1 = ce_1$. We can plug that into the next to get $u_2^* = \frac{e_2 - ce_1}{u_{22}} = de_2 - fe_1$ and so, letting $a_{ij}$ be the coefficient of $e_i$ in the $j$th column of $U^*$, $u_j^* = \sum_{i=1}^{j} a_{ij}e_i$.
Thus, we can see that the $j$th column of $U^*$ has non-zero components on the rows that are less than $j$, thus $U^*$ is upper triangular.

Answer (score 0):

You can prove it by considering the canonical base $e_1, ..e_n$ of $\bf R^n$. let $E_1= vect \{e_1\}$, $E_2=vect \{e_1, e_2\}$,..$E-k=vect \{e_1,..e_k\}$ be the family of increasing subspace generated by the vectors $e_1,..e_k$. We see that the matrix of $U$ is upper triangular  if and only if $U(E_1)\subset E_i$, and by a dimension argument, it is uppper triangular invertible iff $U(E_i)=E_i$. Of course if it is the case, $U^{-1}(E_i)=E_i$ too.

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice way of doing that using graph theory.

Let $G_U:=(V,E)$ be the directed adjacency graph associated with the matrix $U\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ defined as $V=\{1,\ldots,n\}$ and $(i,j)\in E$ if $u_{ij}\ne 0$, $i\ne j$.

Assuming that $U$ is invertible, it is known that the entry $(i,j)$ of $U^{-1}$ may only be nonzero if there is a path from node $i$ to node $j$ in the graph $G_U$.

If $U$ is upper-triangular, then the graph is acyclic and we only have edges connecting vertices in increasing order. In this regard, the only possible nonzero entries of $U^{-1}$ are in the upper-triangular part.